# Redeploy a smart contract on the same address

Tags: selfdestruct

How can I redeploy a different smart contract on the same address after selfdestruct()?

I know that with CREATE2 I can place a smart contract on a specific address. But after I remove the source code from that address through selfdestruct() how can I redeploy a different smart contract on that same address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the contract was deployed using `CREATE` opcode (the normal contract deployment), then it's impossible. Because the address is calculated based on the deployer's nonce `new_address` is derived from `keccak256(sender, nonce)`. And your deployer nonce is always increasing.

If the contract was deployed using `CREATE2` opcode in [EIP-1014](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014) then YES, it's possible because the contract address is deterministic: `new_address` is derived from `keccak256(0xFF, sender, salt, bytecode)`. You can take a look at how to use `CREATE2` in [very details from openzeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/deploying-with-create2)

About CREATE2, although the address is computed using hash of the bytecode, there was an interesting method to deploy arbitrary bytecode on the same address with this [Metamorphosis Smart Contracts pattern](https://ethereum-blockchain-developer.com/110-upgrade-smart-contracts/12-metamorphosis-create2/)

Comment: But so when you see a contract that was "Reinit" on Etherscan, does it mean it has the same bytecode, or do people brute-force their way into finding a salt that gives the same address for a given new bytecode?